# SSRS Keep Together property doesn't work

Tags: reporting-services

i have a report page,and inside of it,near the end of the page there is a 6x3 table. when i run the report,first row is shown in the first page,and the other 5 rows are shown in the second page even if the keep together property is set to True. Does not the Keep Together property mean that keep all the rows together . How can i fix that ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Also note that putting the table in a sub-report, and then setting the sub-report Keep Together property to true, will keep the whole table together.

Answer (score 4):

The keep together property attempts to keep individual rows on the same page, not all the rows.
i.e, if you have a detailed row that is filled with content spanning multiple lines, that will still be kept together in the same page when possible.

One possible solution might be to put a rectangle in that page, and putting the table inside the rectangle. Not 100% sure it will work, but that is what I would try.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem.  The solution is to right click on the table, Add Group, and put everything you want unbroken up in the same group.

Comment: That worked for me, and it overcame the fact that I have a sub-report on my second row. Then I hid the new column and made the width as close to zero as I could to hide it from my report.